# Ошибка при сравнении объектов

Tags: java, junit

При тестировании проверяются два метода. В первом мы сравниваем аналогичные объекты из списка, один из которых получен из класса `DAOImpl`, а другой из `ServiceImpl`,созданный на основе `DAOImpl`.

Во втором делаем тоже самое, но сравниваем два идентичных объекта, полученных по id из двух описанных выше классов.

По итогу тестирование проходит только второй метод.

```
public class FilmServiceImplTest {

private FilmDAOImpl filmDAO = new FilmDAOImpl();
private FilmServiceImpl filmService = new FilmServiceImpl();

@Test
public void allFilms() {
    Assert.assertEquals(filmDAO.allFilms(2), filmService.allFilms(2));
}

@Test
public void getById() {
    Assert.assertEquals(filmDAO.getById(5), filmService.getById(5));
}}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы `equals` переопределили?

У вас во втором случае, как понимаю, сравниваются ссылки на один и тот же объект, поэтому тест проходит.

В первом же случае объекты разные (хоть и их члены одинаковые), поэтому и валится тест. Переопределите `equals` в вашем `FilmDAOImpl` классе.

Что-то вроде:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (this == o) 
        return true;

    if (o == null)
        return false;

    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) 
        return false;  

    final A a = (A) o;
    // здесь все поля проверяем
    return a.year == this.year && this.genre.equals(a.genre);
}
```

Comment: Переопределил метод equals() в классе Film, объекты которого и хранились в списках и все прошло

Comment: @АртемКосенко вот и отлично)